# How to add two matrix with different dimensions

Tags: r

I want to add two matrices but both have different dimension.  I want to add them based on row and column names. For example: I have 2 matrices m1 and m2,

```
m1<- matrix(rep(1,9),3,3)
row.names(m1)<- c("a", "b", "c")
colnames(m1)<- c("a", "b", "c")

m2<- matrix(rep(1,4),2,2)
row.names(m2)<- c("a", "c")
colnames(m2)<- c("a", "c")
> m1
  a b c
a 1 1 1
b 1 1 1
c 1 1 1
> m2
  a c
a 1 1
c 1 1
```

I want output like this

```
  a b c
a 2 1 2
b 1 1 1
c 2 1 2
```

I found one such link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337411/8973131) but it is based on the column names only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rownames` and `colnames` to subset *m1* and make the addition.

```
m1[rownames(m2), colnames(m2)] <- m1[rownames(m2), colnames(m2)] + m2
m1
#  a b c
#a 2 1 2
#b 1 1 1
#c 2 1 2
```

In case `m1` has not all names of `m2`:

```
i <- intersect(rownames(m1), rownames(m2))
j <- intersect(colnames(m1), colnames(m2))
m1[i, j] <- m1[i, j] + m2[i, j]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it's super easy.

Comment: Hi! when i did the same exercise with my actual matrix which are of dimensions 37*37 and 26*26 respectively, I got the error message ' Error in m[rownames(m1), colnames(m1)] : subscript out of bounds' .  Here m (37*37) is my 1st matrix and m1(26*26) is the other.

Comment: Does `m` contain *all* `rownames` and `colnames` of `m1`?

Comment: Yes, m contains all rows of m1, and the problem has been resolved, some of the row names had extra space in the end. when I corrected it, I got the output. Thanks!!